# Binary search tree invalid use of data member

Tags: c++, eclipse, binary-search-tree

I am getting invalid use of non-static data member for my root variable when I write it into the below functions as default parameter.

```
class Leaf {
    Item* data;
    Leaf* parent;
    Leaf* left;
    Leaf* right;
    friend class binaryTree;

    Leaf(Item* data, Leaf* parent = 0, Leaf* left = 0, Leaf* right = 0) :
            data(data), parent(parent), left(left), right(right) {
    }
    ~Leaf() {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
};

class binaryTree {
    Leaf* root;
public:
    binaryTree() :
            root(0) {
    }

    ~binaryTree() {
        delete root;
    }

    void insert(Item* data, Leaf* &node = root) {
        if (!node) {
            node = new Leaf(data);
        } else {
            if (data->neptun < node->data->neptun) {
                insert(data, node->left);
            } else {
                insert(data, node->right);
            }
        }
    }

    void listForward(Leaf* node = root) {
        if (!node) {
            listForward(node->left);
            cout<<" "<<node->data->neptun;
            listForward(node->right);
        }
    }
};
```

How can I fix this? I don't like to make a workaround like making these private functions and call them via another function with only the root in parameter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make the no-node versions separate overloads, which defer to the with-node versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the default parameter `=root` and add those two extra functions to your
 `bynaryTree` class

```
void insert(Item* data) {
  insert(Item* data, root);
}
void listForward() {
  listForward(root);
}
```

Comment: But why can't I use default parameter?

Comment: My guess is that default parameters to functions have to be constant, cannot be variables. You cannot use a variable (like a mamber variable) as a default parameter because every time you call the function the inputs would be different.
The only way of doing that is to declare `root` as a `static const member`, which means that it's value is constant (you cannot change it) and the same for all the instances of your class.